# Can a Hindu declare as false scripturally-based beliefs of other Hindus?

Tags: gods, sin

If I recall right, there are denigrations of some Hindu Gods, belief in some Hindu Gods and/or their devotees in scripture. Is this considered dharmic?

Comment: Shankara has said that the various means of interpreting the scriptures are for the learned, not for liberation. All the quarrels that occur between the different sects are between form, not of substance. Perhaps the Lord has made those other interpretations available as different minds require different interpretations. Realize God and ask Him directly which is correct. Until then, how do you know that your interpretation is not the false belief?

Comment: *Can a Hindu declare as false scripturally-based beliefs of other Hindus?* Yes, a Hindu can declare such a thing, it is legitimate, and there are many examples of that in the history of Hinduism. For example Vedanta traditions has often rejected explanations of the competitor Vedanta traditions. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Please expand into an answer @Swami Vishwananda

Comment: @SK - Can you please substantiate this with specific example(s) - "If I recall right, there are denigrations of some Hindu Gods, belief in some Hindu Gods and/or their devotees in scripture. Is this considered dharmic?" This seems rather vague.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a Hindu denigrate another Hindu's beliefs?

**No, a Hindu is not allowed to denigrate another Hindu's beliefs.**

Denigration is [defined](https://www.google.com/search?q=denigration&oq=denigration&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i57j69i60l2j69i61.927j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as:

> The action of ***unfairly*** criticizing someone or something.

This is wrong.

However, you can *fairly* criticize someone's beliefs if you think those beliefs are incorrect, and many people have done this in the past, and continue to do so now.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a Hindu declare as false scripturally-based beliefs of other Hindus?

Yes, a Hindu can declare such a thing, it is legitimate, and there are many examples of that in the history of Hinduism. For example Vedanta traditions has often rejected explanations of the competitor Vedanta traditions. Nothing wrong with that.

Sometimes the beliefs of other Hindus are not proclaimed as false, but are criticized. We have such examples in the scriptures. Here "criticize" means "indicate the faults of (someone or something) in a disapproving way". We see examples of all this even stated by Lord Krishna himself in the Bhagavad-gita.

Thus Lord Krishna says in the Bhagavad-gita 7.15 (all translations from the vedabase):

> Those miscreants who are grossly foolish, who are lowest among mankind, whose knowledge is stolen by illusion, and who partake of the atheistic nature of demons **do not surrender unto Me**.

And also He says in verse 7.20:

> Those whose **intelligence has been stolen** by material desires **surrender unto demigods** and follow the particular rules and regulations of worship according to their own natures.

And also in 9.24:

> I am the only enjoyer and master of all sacrifices. Therefore, **those who do not recognize** My true transcendental nature **fall down**.

Also in 9.11-13:

> **Fools deride Me when I descend in the human form.** They **do not know My transcendental nature** as the Supreme Lord of all that be. 
>   Those **who are thus bewildered** are attracted by **demonic and atheistic** views. In that **deluded** condition, **their hopes for liberation**, their fruitive activities, and their culture of knowledge **are all defeated**.
>   O son of Pṛthā, those **who are not deluded**, the **great souls**, are under the protection of the divine nature. **They are fully engaged in devotional service** because **they know Me** as the Supreme Personality of Godhead, original and inexhaustible.

Also verses 7.24-25:

> **Unintelligent men**, who **do not know Me** perfectly, **think that I**, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, **was impersonal before and have now assumed this personality**. **Due to their small knowledge, they do not know** My higher nature, which is imperishable and supreme. 
>   **I am never manifest to the foolish and unintelligent**. For them I am covered by My internal potency, and therefore **they do not know** that I am unborn and infallible.

Thus beliefs of some Hindus are criticized by the Lord himself in those verses.

Comment: overlooking the "Vedabase" angle - there is no criticism of scripturally based belief in the material cited @brahma jijnasa

Comment: @SK Actually what Lord Krishna was criticizing in all those verses can be a scripturally based beliefs of some Hindus, namely some Hindus may be studying scriptures and thus they formulate certain beliefs which Lord Krishna criticise in those verses.

Answer (score 0):

No, its never allowed.

The Prayer in the Taittiriya-Upanishad says

> **maa** **vidvishavahai**

meaning May we never have hatred between us.

Sri Chaitanyadeva has instructed

> Never criticise others' deities or scriptures (Ref:Chaitanyacharitamrita quoted in Sri Sri Chaitanyadeva, Swami Saradeshananda,Udbodhan, Page 217).

This is our culture. **The famous Chicago speech of Swami Vivekananda beautifully expressed our culture.**

Criticism on non-Hindu scriptures are also not allowed.

Comment: By Chaitanyadeva you mean [Chaitanya Mahaprabhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Mahaprabhu)? See what he said about Muslims [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/adi/17/).

Comment: @sv please read unbiased translations of Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita.

Comment: Ok, give me a link to unbiased translation. Also, where are you quoting 'Never criticise others' deities or religions' from? Please add the source. 'He said' is not a source.

Comment: @sv. please read the translation of sri charisma charitamrita by Dimmock.Edward C. Dimock, Jr., is Distinguished Service Professor Emeritus, University of Chicago

Comment: What is Charishma Charitamrita? How can you judge what is biased and what is unbiased translation?

Comment: @sarvabhouma That typo i hope wd be corrected by addresses.And i judge biased and unbiased on basis of reading original and translation using the intellect God has provided me. – Partha 6 hours ago    Delete
add a comment

Comment: Ok, I read [that translation](https://archive.org/details/DimocksCC1stHalf/page/n191) and even that says all Muslims (being cow-killers) will rot in hell. It also says _munis_ used to kill old cows and brought them back to life using Vedic mantras. I doubt if this is possible.